# Convert NSFileManager file path in Swift to NSURL

Tags: swift, file, ftp, nsurl

I have a file on my app I've stored dynamically using NSFileManager. when I loop through all the files I can see the full path to the file:

```
let fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
for(var i:Int = 0; i < count; i++){
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(fileList[i]) != true {
        print("File path: \(fileList[i])")
    }
}
```

I get the correct path, in this case: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/123321ABF/Documents/myFile.zip`

All good until here. But then I'd like to upload it to an FTP server and for that I need to turn the path into NSURL but this doesn't seem to work, like it can't find the file, I've tried:

```
let url = NSURL(string: fileList[i])
```

and

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileList[i], isDirectory: false)
```

but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Simple answer is below

```
 let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: stringofURL)! //replace stringofURL to Path
```

> Example

```
// just a string
 var stringUrl = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/123321ABF/Documents/myFile.zip"
 // convert path to NSURL

   let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!

     print (URL) // print url
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

let files = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtURL(documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [], errorHandler: nil)
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        print("***")
        let modFile = file as! NSURL
        print("FILE: \(modFile)")
        print("***")
    }
```

If I understood you wrong, please feel free to correct me! Regards, Alex